# How can I use publicExponent as 65537 in RSA-OAEP algorithm in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, padding

Actually, I am using  RSA-OAEP with SHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING for encryption  and decryption in JavaScript using Web crypto API. The actual scenario I need to do is in java I am able to encrypt and decrypt using a public and private key with the same algorithm specifications. but there it uses a 65537 public exponent .now what I need to do is encrypt some message in JavaScript using public key and decrypt it in java. but I found that in JavaScript for the above-mentioned algorithm specification it uses Public exponent as 5. so I want to change it to 65537. I tried to use the following code in JavaScript.

```
  window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({
     name: "RSA-OAEP",
     modulusLength: 2048,
     publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 0x01]),
     hash: {name: "SHA-256"},
    }, 
true, 
 ["encrypt", "decrypt"]);
```

but still, the public exponent of the generated public key is 5. what wrong I am doing? The final requirement of me is, Encrypt some message in JavaScript using RSA-OAEP with SHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING  and which will be able to decrypt in java using the private key and vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this. It is equivalent to 65537:

```
 publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01])
```

The `publicExponent` is a [BigInteger](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/#big-integer) Each element in the uint8 array is a non negative integer in the range 0..256

> 16. BigInteger

> ```
> typedef Uint8Array BigInteger;
> ```

> The BigInteger typedef is a Uint8Array that holds an arbitrary magnitude unsigned integer in big-endian order.

```
[0x01, 0x00, 0x01] = 00000001 00000000 00000001 = 65537
```

Comment: if i use publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01])
 then the exponent value will be 5. is it possible that i can use 65537 in rsa oaep?

Comment: i need to do the decryption in javascript using the private key which is generated from the java code using this algorithm spec. how do that possible. give me some code

Comment: The uint8array value I provided is equivalent to 65537. Why you say that the value is 5? You're probably inspecting the public key badly. You can see examples here https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/blob/master/README.md#rsa-oaep

Comment: but after generating the public key exponent  is displayed as [1,0,1] is that 5?

Comment: are you saying by default in webcrypto API RSA -OAEP with SHA-256 uses MGF-1 and public exponent as 65537?

Comment: `[0x01,0x00,0x01]= 65537` I've detailed it in the answer